# Error importing variables into another Python + QTDesigner file

Tags: python, import

I want to import some variables that I have in one `.py` file to another. I don't know if I did it the right way, but it sends me an error that won't let me do it.

```
# THESE ARE THE VARIABLES I WANT TO IMPORT ARE:
VARIABLE_1
VARIABLE_2
VARIABLE_3
```

The error is as follows:

> AttributeError: module 'preapnapro' does not have attribute
> 'button_agree'

My code is the following:

**variables.py** (where are the variables):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import os
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets

qtCreatorFile = "preset-añadir_productos.ui" # Nombre del archivo aquí.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_agree.clicked.connect(self.boton_agree)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(301, 370)
        
        
    def boton_agree(self):
        introduce_producto = self.Inp_nombre_de_producto.text()
        introduce_precio = self.Inp_nombre_de_precio.text() 
        introduce_marca = self.Inp_nombre_de_marca.text()
        
        if introduce_producto + introduce_precio + introduce_marca=="":
                print("El producto no ha sido añadido correctamente")
                
                cmd = 'producto_no_añadido.py'
                os.system(cmd)
        else :
            print(introduce_producto)
            print(introduce_precio)
            print(introduce_marca)
            
            
        if introduce_precio.count(",") >0:
                print("has introducido una coma")
                cmd = 'se_ha_introducido_una_coma.py'
                os.system(cmd)
                
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**import.py** (where I want to import them):

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5 import uic, QtWidgets
import preañapro

qtCreatorFile = "productos_p2.ui" # Nombre del archivo aquí.
Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


class MyApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    
    
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_plus.clicked.connect(self.boton_plus)
        self.pushButton_edit.clicked.connect(self.boton_edit)
        self.pushButton_delete.clicked.connect(self.boton_remove)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint | Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        self.setFixedSize(450, 700)
        
        
        with open("coma.csv", 'w') as coma_write:
            coma_write = coma_write.write(",")
            
        with open("coma.csv", "r") as coma:
            coma = coma.read()
            
            
        with open("productos.csv", 'r') as login:
            login = login.read()
            contador = login.count(coma)
            print(contador)
            
            introduce_producto = preañapro.boton_agree()
            introduce_precio = preañapro.boton_agree()
            introduce_marca = preañapro.boton_agree()
            
            introduce_producto = introduce_producto.replace(",", "")
            introduce_precio = introduce_precio.replace(",", "")
            introduce_marca = introduce_marca.replace(",", "")
            
                    
            self.Productos1.setPlainText(introduce_producto)
            self.Productos1_2.setPlainText(introduce_precio)
            self.Productos1_3.setPlainText(introduce_marca)
            self.introduce_producto = self.productos1.text()
            if not self.introduce_producto == "":
                self.Productos2.setPlainText(introduce_producto)
                self.Productos3.setPlainText(introduce_precio)
                self.Productos4.setPlainText(introduce_marca)
                        
                    
    def boton_plus(self):
        cmd = 'preañapro.py'
        os.system(cmd)
            
    def boton_edit(self):
        self.label.setParent(None)
        
    def boton_remove(self):
        self.label.setParent()
  
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app =  QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to make a contact directory that is why I want the variables in another file so I can write them in the user interface. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: So, how did you try to import `variables.py` into `import.py`?

Comment: Exactly they are already imported so to speak, the problem is the error that it returns